# Remove XML Header and Footer nodes using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have console app which i am trying to automate , there is manual process to remove headers and footer tags form .trg file . Can anyone suggest how to remove headers and footers using c sharp.

Header looks like this.

```
<Batch remotefolder="\\srv-dg-procl13\nexdox\nxtil04\process\200863-142325x-mkts\output\archive\absamples_pims_pdf\" grid="200863-142325X-MKTS" streamID="ABSAMPLES_PIMS_PDF" delivertobox="False">
  <Application application="NXTIL04" name="Mifid 10 percent drop Notification " output="ABSAMPLES_PIMS_PDF">
    <Indexes>
      <Index name="Reference" description="Reference" type="StringDefinition" visible="True" />
    </Indexes>
  </Application>
```

footer looks like this .

```
</Batch>
```

This is what i am trying to do but not working .

```
private void RemoveHeader(string Xlfile)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load(Xlfile);

            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectSingleNode("Batch"))
            {
                doc.RemoveAll();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath is your friend here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

    namespace testconsole
    {
            class Program
            {
                    public static string strFileName = "c:\\temp\\test.xml";
                    static void Main(string[] args) {
                            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                            xml.Load(strFileName);

                            XmlElement ndMatch = (XmlElement)xml.SelectSingleNode("//Application");

                            if (ndMatch != null) {
                                    XmlDocument xmlNew = new XmlDocument();
                                    xmlNew.LoadXml(ndMatch.OuterXml);
                                    xmlNew.Save(strFileName + ".new");
                            } else {
                                    Console.Write("Cannot load " + strFileName);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: thanks , tried your code in new file i have only xml header which i want to remove ,

Comment: <Batch remotefolder="\\srv-dg-procl13\nexdox\nxtil04\process\200863-142325x-mkts\output\archive\absamples_pims_pdf\" grid="200863-142325X-MKTS" streamID="ABSAMPLES_PIMS_PDF" delivertobox="False">
  <Application application="NXTIL04" name="Mifid 10 percent drop Notification " output="ABSAMPLES_PIMS_PDF">
    <Indexes>
      <Index name="Reference" description="Reference" type="StringDefinition" visible="True" />
    </Indexes>
  </Application>

Comment: sorry got your point  actually your code is not removing the tag i just your code to select the innner xml which i am interested and this saves it as new file . it works for me . thanks for your help